# Adding sort to Objectify query causes empty result

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm experimenting with App Engine, Datastore and Objectify 4. I have a working Objectify query that fetches all entities of a given kind from the Datastore. I'm trying to sort the result based on a date:

```
List<MyEntity> entities = OfyService.ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).order("-createdDate").list();
```

But after I add order, the query returns 0 records. This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity
{   
    @Id Long id;
    Long userID;
    @Ignore String username;
    @Index String name;
    String url;
    String description;
    @Index Date createdDate;
    @Index int viewCount;
}
```

I've tried to order by other data types with no success. Why does this happen?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the full code, but do you get results if you remove the `-` in the `order()` to return results in ascending order?  According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_configuration), App Engine should automatically create an index for _Queries with no filters and only one sort order on a property, either ascending or descending_.

Comment: I get the same result when removing the "-" from order(). For some reason, none of the indexes defined in the entity class are stored in the datastore, please read the answer I just added

Answer (score 2):

We need to define index manually in WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="AppMedia" ancestor="false">
        <property name="createdDate" direction="desc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

Then the index is created properly and the query will work. 
**Note** : The query will only work with those rows added after the index is configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the datastore through cloud.google.com and when opening any entity, all the fields were marked as "Not indexed", including the fields that are defined with @Index in my entity class. When I manually marked the fields "Indexed" in the datastore, the query with sort worked. Shouldn't all fields that are marked with @Index in the entity be indexed in the datastore when saved through Objectify? What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, they _should_, but without seeing the full entity class, it's hard to say with certainty.  Was the `@Index` annotation present when the entities were first created?  If not, you would need to re-save the entities after adding the `@Index` annotation. You would have done this implicitly when modifying the index rules through the cloud console.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this comment does not turn out to be the answer.

Comment: I did probably save some entities in the datastore before adding the @Index to createdDate. But regardless, any new entity I save after adding the annotation should be stored with the index right? As for the existing ones, I tried to fetch all of them in a method and then just resave them, still all of fields are marked as "Not indexed". Updated my question with the full entity